# Qt: size of QLabel in a QDockWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel, qdockwidget

I created a left `QDockWidget`, and added 2 `QLabel` into it.
I want a squared size for my labels (by default 100x100).

So when the user increases the width of the `QDockWidget`, how should I force my labels to keep a squared size?

I tried a lot of things, without any success :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you shall overwrite the [int QWidget::heightForWidth( int aWidth ) const](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#heightForWidth) function. So you need to create your own `QLabel` subclass.

```
class MyLabel
{
public:
    virtual int heightForWidth( int aWidth ) const override
    {
        return aWidth; // So it will be square.
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the solution.

I create this subclass :

```
class SquareLabel : public QLabel
{
public:
    SquareLabel(QWidget* parent = 0) : QLabel(parent)
    {
        setMinimumSize(100, 100);

        QSizePolicy pol(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
        pol.setHeightForWidth(true);
        setSizePolicy(pol);
    }
    virtual int heightForWidth(int w) const { return w; }
    virtual QSize sizeHint() const { int w = this->width(); return QSize(w, heightForWidth(w)); }

protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event) { }
};
```

All my labels are added in a QVBoxLayout, and I need this property :

```
layout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
```

Now, I need to resize my pixmap in my label.
I will post it before close this question.